# Как добавить новую библиотеку в Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

только начинаю изучать Airflow, возник вопрос. Поставил airflow с docker-compose при написании dag'a использую библиотеку pandas-datareader.
Вылезает такая ошибка:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/full_data_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/full_data_dag.py", line 5, in <module>
    from project import get_full_data
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/project/get_full_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader as web
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Код самого dag'а:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator
from project import get_full_data
from project import preprocessing
from project import model_train

dag = DAG('full_process', description='Loading full data, train model',
          schedule_interval='@once',
          start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 19), catchup=False)

def get_data():
    get_full_data

get_data = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='get_data',
    python_callable=get_data,
    requirements=['pandas_datareader'],
    dag=dag)

def make_preprocessing():
    preprocessing

preprocess = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='preprocessing',
    python_callable=make_preprocessing,
    requirements=['pandas, numpy, sklearn, joblib'],
    dag=dag)

def train():
    model_train

training = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='model_training',
    python_callable=train,
    requirements=['numpy, sklearn, joblib'],
    dag=dag)

get_data >> preprocess >> training
```

Оператор get_data выполняет python файл, в котором используется библиотека pandas_datareader

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу добавить новую библиотеку?

Comment: Вытащил код из файла, который импортируется в оператор dag'a и просто вставил его в оператор. Все получилось, но вопрос тогда в другом. Как импортировать целиком файл и чтобы библиотеки работали, а не засорять dag лишним кодом?

Answer (score 0):

В системе не хватает зависимости `pandas-datareader`

Для установки введите в терминал следующую команду:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Документация к зависимости: 
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Можете указать установку зависимости в своём docker файле.

Comment: А через строчку в операторе можно как то сделать?     requirements=['pandas_datareader'],

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос. При использовании кода из другого файла, нужно в этом файле все обернуть в функцию. Напишу пример.

Так работать не будет:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(...)
```

А так работать будет:

```
def pandas_read():
    import pandas as pd
    pd.read_csv(...)
```

А в самом dag'e делать импорт этой функции из файла

```
from project.file_name import pandas_read
```

И в операторе запускать уже функцию pandas_read